# Laravel - show and hide elements depending on a user state

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a time tracker so that users can check in and check out.

So there are two buttons which I want to show only one at a time using Blade templating engine.
This buttons insert into database datetime of start and end of working day.

It is not a logged in status. User can start working day, log out or whatever, and then see only check out button, because user is checked in.

```
@if ( //checked in )
   // button
@endif
```

I feel that there should be a variable to set and then check it's state and show a button.

Question:

How to properly store user's status? Store it in a database? Or what else should I use?

Comment: Yes, store it in the database. Please add some more information, what is this checkin/checkout? is it the login status of a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table:

```
user_status_in (id, user_id, date, time,status)
```

Ensure that there's a unique index for user_id, date, status (so the DB doesn't let a user check in or out twice in the same day.

Your user model:

```
public function checkIn() {
      return $this->hasMany(UserCheckIn::class,"user_check_in");
}

public function checkedInToday() { //True if checked in today
      return $this->checkIn()
            ->where("date","=",date_format(date_create(), "Y-m-d")) //today
            ->where("status","=",1)
            ->count() > 0;

}
```

**UserCheckIn.php**

```
class UserCheckIn extends Model {
      public function user() {
             return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
      }
}
```

In your view you can do something like:

```
@if (auth()->user()->checkedInToday())
     //Check out button
@else 
     //Check in button
@endif
```

You can check a user in by doing something like:

```
$c = new UserCheckIn();
$c->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
$c->date = date_format(date_create(), "Y-m-d"));
$c->time = date_format(date_create(), "H-i-s"));
$c->status = 1;
$c->save();
```

Or with status 0 to check out.

This way you can also keep a historic record of check-ins/outs

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to store status in the `users` table. Create a column of `boolean`type named `status`.

Then to check status of a current user you'll be able to use `auth()` global helper:

```
@if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->status)
    // button
@endif
```

Or `Auth` facade:

```
@if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->status)
    // button
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

With Laravel >5.3

```
@if (Auth::check())
    You are signed in.
@else
    You are not signed in.
@endif
```

or

```
@unless (Auth::check())
    You are not signed in.
@endunless
```

or

```
@auth
    // The user is authenticated...
@endauth

@guest
    // The user is not authenticated...
@endguest
```